# Why does my RxObservable never fire?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a hard-coded observable sequence that is zipped with an interval sequence. The intention is to introduce a delay for each element.

The expected output is:

```
1
2
3
Done.
```

Here is the code:

```
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
        .zipWith(Observable.interval(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (x, y) -> x)
        .subscribe(
            System.out::println, 
            Throwable::printStackTrace, 
            () -> System.out.println("Done. "));
```

However, it never pushes an element, throws an error or calls complete.

Why is this?

Comment: When you tested this, did you `Thread.sleep(3100)` or more?

Comment: No `Thread.sleep` was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main thread probably exits so the process stops before you see any output.

Add a latch or some other mechanism to get the main thread not to quit.

```
CountDownLatch l = new CountDownLatch(1);
Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
          .zipWith(Observable.interval(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (x, y) -> x)
          .subscribe(
              System.out::println,
              Throwable::printStackTrace,
              () -> {
                  System.out.println("Done. ");
                  l.countDown();
              }
          );

l.await();
```

Comment: Fixed the formatting so that it was more like his and didn't require horizontal scrolling. Hope that's okay!